# how to merge audio using ffmpeg, not concat

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-recording

I want audio files to be merged and be the length of the longest one of course.

Not to concat them, which means adding one behind the other.

I tried googling since yesterday night, but didn't found any such thing. Is this really possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is probably possible, but to give you an example I'd like to see the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -i input3`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard found the solution thanks  http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For helping others, I'm posting the solution I found :

http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix

Mixes multiple audio inputs into a single output.

For example

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -i INPUT3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=3:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT
```

Above command will mix 3 input audio streams to a single output with the same duration as the first input and a dropout transition time of 3 seconds.

Comment: I don't need a transition. How do I skip that?

Comment: @chovy have you tried 0 for dropout_transition ?

Comment: I suppose you can just remove `:dropout_transition=3`